# disabling a submit button till validation

Tags: dojo

Is there a way using dojo/dijit to disable the submit button till all the fields in a form are valid. Kind of like having a `dojo > method > onChange` inside the form? So the submit button only becomes enabled when all the form elements have meet their criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a `dijit.form.Form` widget as your form?  If you are, I would suggest connecting to the `Form`'s `onValidStateChange` event.  The [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/form/Form) for this event specifically state your use case:

```
onValidStateChange
Defined by dijit.form._FormMixin
Stub function to connect to if you want to do something (like disable/enable a submit button) when the valid state changes on the form as a whole. Deprecated. Will be removed in 2.0. Use watch("state", ...) instead.
```

The best way to see what events are available for a given widget is to look at the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api) for the widget you are interested in under the "Event Summary" heading.  The dojocampus reference documentation often leaves out examples for references to some of the more obscure features of the widgets.

Comment: YOU DA MAN!!!! (though how am I supposed to know that `onValidStateChange` exists? is there anywhere where the `dojo > method` functions are listed???)

Comment: You mostly have to look at the API Docs, they do a pretty decent job explaining what each property/method/event does for a given widget.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a hidden button which will submit the form. When you click visbile button run a javascript function that validates all the input and then clicks on the hidden button to submit the form. Please find the pseudo code below

```
    <form action="register">
    <input dojoType="dijit.validation.TextBox"/>
    <button onClick="validateall()">submit</button>
    <button id="submitForm" type="submit" hidden="true"/> 
    </form> 

    function validateAll(){
      if(AllOk){
             clearErrorMessage();
             dojo.byId('submitForm').click();
    }else{
     showErrorMessage();
   }
```